# Design issue in Chrome browser only

Tags: html, asp.net, google-chrome, telerik, radwindow

Telerik rad window has rad window inside here.

Inside parent rad window contents gets expanded / collapsed.
When expanded or when a child rad window opens there is empty space created at the bottom of the page. Also the parent rad window showing page has asp.net master page like footer, header etc.

When I increased margin top it controlled the issue to some extent only.

This only occurs in Chrome browser.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the problem you are seeing and of the expected behavior. With mere text we can't know what the problem is.
Also, look into opening child RadWindows outside of the bounds of their parent so you don't need to resize the parent: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening-from-within-dialog.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760396/chrome-automatic-shift-of-web-elements